# How to correctly document require module.exports so that documentation isn't lost?

Tags: javascript, require, webstorm, browserify, jsdoc

I've tried to correctly follow [JSDoc guidelines](http://usejsdoc.org/tags-module.html) for all of my code and it looks like I've properly documented my constructors so that editors are able to recognize arguments:

[image: Documentation appears to work]

But for some reason, when I export the classes as so that they can be required elsewhere, they are no longer recognized anywhere for what they are:

[image: No docs once exported]

Am I missing something in the way I should be exporting the class or documenting the export that's confusing editors when a user requires my library? The require statement itself is working, and editors have no trouble navigating to the source file referenced in the require statement (`'./YLTProfile'`), but the definition information is completely lost for some reason.

---

Here's another example, illustrating how it can see the class definition and I can ctrl+click to navigate to it (definition seen on the right), but it's highlighted white and offers no context or constructor parameter information about the class.

[image]

Comment: It it unconventional for me to be exporting the constructor/class directly? I seem to have fewer problems when `module.exports = { ClassName: ClassName }`, but that makes them more awkward to use, as I have to go `var ClassName = require('./ClassName'); var classInstance = new ClassName.ClassName()`, which seems redundant.

Comment: According to this (http://book.mixu.net/node/ch6.html), what I'm doing seems to be a standard pattern for exporting classes.

Comment: Alain, your example works fine for me in WebStorm 9.0.1. Parameter info shows same parameters as when it is invoked from definition file. Could you please recheck it? 
JSDoc looks reasonable for me.

Comment: Thanks @de1mar I can confirm that I too am using WebStorm 9.0.1, yet the above screenshots continue to be the behaviour I'm seeing. Perhaps you have a different set of global libraries enabled that's enabling this? My only globals are HTML/HTML5.

Comment: I've included one more screenshot illustrating how it can easily find the class I'm referencing, but it treats the identifier as nothing more than an unknown object variable in the editor.

Comment: It actually considers that the identifier has `Agent` type. You can check this by invoking completion after `new Agent()`. **hostname** and **description** should be at the top of popup list and highlighed in bold.
More strict resolve (no resolve for `test`) and better highlighing is expected in WebStorm 10. Could you please create an issue in [our tracker](https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issues/WEB#newissue)?
Global libraries don't affect your case.

Comment: Alright thanks. I just assumed I was doing something wrong but this is really a Webstorm-specific question, so I'll vote to close it.

Comment: @Alain Did you find a solution for this? I'm facing the same problem with PHPStorm.

Comment: @Xplouder I'm afraid I never did - and what's more, I gave up on JavaScript entirely and went back to C# programming :p

Comment: Ahah hope haven't been due this problem! :D thank you anyway

Comment: This question is really more of a bug report and no solution is likely.

Answer (score 0):

It seems that you have to have your module in node_modules, then it will automatically appear in the libraries, or manually add a  library and point to the correct directory that contains your module.